# Div background fit to div size

Tags: html, css

I have div which contains two divs. Like you can see in webpage, they are 50/50 sized. The second div where the picture is, must expand to the size of the div. Now it's only fit by width.

That container div is 600px height.

I can make it fill the whole 600px height, but then it's repeating img or fill that extra space with color. I want that img fill that area nicely in all devices.

```css
.etusivun_teksti {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.etusivu-div-2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.etusivun_kuva {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url("http://www.jsdkqwoj.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/startup-849804-scaled.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .etusivun_kuva {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: 50% 40%;
  }
  .row {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```

```html
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="logodiv justify-content-center">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://www.jsdkqwoj.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/frontpage_logo_v5.svg">
  </div>

  <div name="yritys" class="etusivu-div-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm pt-5 pb-5">
          <h1>MIKÄ HOSSIMOSSI?</h1>
          <div class="etusivun_teksti" data-aos="fade-up">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <?php the_content();?>
            <?php endwhile; endif;?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm etusivun_kuva"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php get_footer();?>
```

This is my site: http://www.jsdkqwoj.eu/ (temporary address)

Comment: Can you try to narrow down the code to something more easily reproducable?

Comment: `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: I don't understand, can you not just add style="height:100%" to div class="container-fluid" and div class="row"?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald I tried that but image height is not enough. After that theres is emty space top and bottom of the image.

Comment: @ecolema I tried that also, not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the `<div>` container that holds the background image titled "HOSSIMOSSI" to cover the entire height of the viewport.

In your live website you can adjust the `logodiv` class to have a height equivalent to viewport screen:

```
.logodiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    margin: 180px 0 180px 0;
}
```

[image: example]

**Note**: This would work for smaller devices as well.

Comment: I don't have problems in that div. ```div class="row"``` there is two divs inside of it, first ```div class="col-sm pt-5 pb-5"``` and second ```div class="col-sm etusivun_kuva"```. That second div have background image and it is too "short" for the ```container-fluid```.